# Am I using the correct notation for this external cross product proof?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, homology-cohomology

From Rotman's Algebraic Topology:  I'm trying to prove $^*12.13$ from the below picture with required definitions and am having some trouble with the notation.

My proof so far:

If (by definition of the cross product) $$f^* \text{cls } \phi \times g^* \text{cls } \theta = \alpha '(f^* \text{cls } \phi \otimes g^* \text{cls } \theta) = \text{cls }(\zeta^{\text{#}}(\phi f_{\text{#}} \otimes \theta g_{\text{#}})) $$
$$(f \times g)^*(\text{cls } \phi \times \text{cls } \theta) = (f \times g)^*(\alpha ' (\text{cls } \phi \otimes \text{cls } \theta)) = (f \times g)^*(\text{cls }(\zeta^{\text{#}}(\phi \otimes \theta))) = \text{cls }(\zeta^{\text{#}}(\phi \otimes \theta)(f \times g)_{\text{#}}) $$

My next step would be to show that the final equalities are equal, but I'm not sure how I would show that or if what I'm doing is notationally correct.

Is what I've done the notationally correct?  And if so, how would I continue this proof?

---

[image]

Comment: what is cls? ${}{}{}$

Comment: $\text{cls } \phi $ is an element of the cohomology group $H^p(X ; R) = Z(X;R) / B(X;R)= \ker \partial_{n+1}^{\text{#}} / \text{im }(\partial_n^{\text{#}})$ where $\partial_n^{\text{#}} : \text{Hom}(S_n(X), R) \rightarrow \text{Hom}(S_{n+1}(X), R) $.

Comment: Is Rotman really going to write "cls" in front of every cohomology element in the entire textbook? Or is it only when he knows the cochain?

Comment: In Rotman's book every element of a cohomology group is written with the cls notation.